# Insert string to button onclick location.href Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button like this:

```
<button id="sync"  type="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://localhost/manage/test_yeezy/yooo/massSync/key/23ds31231ada/';" data-ui-id="sync-button">
    <span>Sync All</span>
</button>
```

i want to insert a string  **/listing_id/45/** like this after the **massSync/**, the url can be dynamic, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to do this inside the HTML itself, as we cannot use variables here, you need to write it in a separate script tag, if that is fine with you, i can post an  answer.

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed i'm using a framework that generate that url automatically, thats why i need to use javascript

Comment: as @SharjeelAhmed said, you can do that jquery's onclick event and you can change href attrbiute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish this in the following way ...

```js
var link = 'http://localhost/manage/test_yeezy/yooo/massSync/key/23ds31231ada/';
var newLink = link.replace(/(massSync)/, '$1/listing_id/45');
$('#sync').attr("onclick", "location.href = '" + newLink + "'");
var location_href = $('#sync').attr('onclick').replace('location.href = ', '');
console.log(location_href);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sync"  type="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://localhost/manage/test_yeezy/yooo/massSync/key/23ds31231ada/';" data-ui-id="sync-button">
    <span>Sync All</span>
</button>
```

** *assuming `massSync` is static*

Comment: @slam how to inject it to the button?

Comment: You should use a function and pass the URL to function and then put the code in the function and `window.location` as well.

Comment: Can you change the button `HTML`?

Comment: @siam how to retrieve the current button location.href and store it to variable?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 i can't, the button is generated by the framework